# IdHTTP: EIdException ResponseCode (Colorize + Replace)

Tags: indy10, idhttp, c++builder-10-seattle

I have two problems here. So I need your help.

1. The result of microsoft.com's response code is some time HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden or HTTP/1.1 200 OK.`

   ```
   try 
   {
       IdHTTP->Get("http://www.microsoft.com");
       ListBox->Items->Add(IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode);
   }
   catch (const EIdException &E) 
   {
       ListBox->Items->Add(E.Message);
       ListBox->Items->Add(IdHTTP->Response->ResponseText);
   }
   ```

   But when I checked it on `http://web-sniffer.net/` or `http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker` then its results is `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`.

   Why the results from IdHTTP is different from the both url above?. How can IdHTTP achieve the same http status code?.
2. Colorize & replace E.Message error of EIdException / Exception in TListBox.

   For example, I want to replace the `"Socket Error # 10061Connection refused"` with `"your connection is refused".`

   ```
   ListBox->Items->Add(StringReplace(E.Message,"Socket Error # 10061Connection refused.","your connection is refused.",TReplaceFlags()<<rfReplaceAll));
   ```

   But using that way, the result is still same.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Any help or suggestions with would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of site maintenance, I doubt `http://www.microsoft.com` would ever return a `403 Forbidden` error under normal conditions.  But, like any site, I suppose it *could* happen at times.  It is a fatal error, you cannot access the URL at that time (if at all).

`302 Moved Temporarily` is an HTTP redirect.  The `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event will be triggered to give you the new URL.  If the `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` property is true, or the `OnRedirect` event handler returns true, `TIdHTTP` will handle the redirect internally and automatically request the new URL for you.  `TIdHTTP.Get()` does not exit until the final URL is reached, or an error occurs.

As for error handling, if you want to customize the message you display based on the type of error that occurred, you need to actually differentiate between the various types of errors that can occur, eg:

```
try 
{
    IdHTTP->Get("http://www.microsoft.com");
    ListBox->Items->Add(IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode);
}
catch (const EIdHTTPProtocolException &E) 
{
    // HTTP error
    // E.ErrorCode contains the ResponseCode
    // E.Message contains the ResponseText
    // E.ErrorMessage contains the content of the error body, if any

    ListBox->Items->Add(E.Message);
}
catch (const EIdSocketError &E)
{
    // Socket error
    // E.LastError contains the socket error code
    // E.Message contains the socket error message

    if (E.LastError == Id_WSAECONNREFUSED)
        ListBox->Items->Add("Your connection is refused");
    else
        ListBox->Items->Add(E.Message);
}
catch (const EIdException &E) 
{
    // any other Indy error
    ListBox->Items->Add(E.Message);
}
catch (const Exception &E) 
{
    // any other non-Indy error
    ListBox->Items->Add(E.Message);
}
```

Comment: `Remy:`  Hi smart mate, even though I've tried to used `IdHTTP->OnRedirect = IdHTTPRedirect; - (Handled = true;),` or `IdHTTP->HandleRedirects = true;` or even use both of them directly, but `http://www.microsoft.com` still always return a 403 Forbidden. So, how to solve this problem ?. Thank you so much for your time and direction, anyway. - Love IndyProject -.

Comment: 403 is not a redirect. 302 is. What you describe suggests Microsoft is redirecting to a URL you do not have access to.  What is the actual URL being reported in the `OnRedirect` event before the 403 error occurs? Can you show the complete headers of each HTTP request/response between your initial request and the final 403 response? Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark or Fiddler, or attach a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP`, to get that information.

Comment: `Remy,` it works so handsomely now. Thank you so much for your advice, gentlemen!. - Love IndyProject -.